# how do I fix the type mismatch issue?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming job and had a question about type converting. the below is my code:

```
val component = data.get("viewed_objects").get.asInstanceOf[ListBuffer[Map[String, Any]]]
```

but the exception is

> scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to scala.collection.ListBuffer

what caused the issue and how do I fix it?

Comment: yes,it is a json String,like this:  u'data': {u'viewed_objects': [{u'location': 3, u'keyword': u'baby carriers'}]}

Comment: I print the data value, it is for example: data:Map(viewed_objects -> List(Map(location -> 2, category_name -> Toys, Kids & Babies, category_id -> 27))), how do I get the viewed_objects and traversal the elements

Comment: I would get the viewed_objects list and deal with every element in the list

Comment: And you don't get that error for the data you have given in the comments. you get the error when you do `.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]`. So you are just mixing code and errors. Please test it again and update with the right code and right error message and of course sample data as well

Comment: I don't get your point, let me debug

Comment: all I am saying is if you do `data.get("viewed_objects").get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]` then you get `scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map` but if you do `data.get("viewed_objects").get.asInstanceOf[ListBuffer[Map[String, Any]]]` you should get `scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer` Is it clear now? so you are just mixing thigs up

Comment: ok,I see, maybe I need to edit it

Comment: yeah, you are right, I had fixed it ,thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scala `scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon` simply means that the data is `scala.collection.immutable.List` since `List` are the generated using `cons` (`::`) notation.

So the error

> scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to scala.collection.ListBuffer

means that you are trying to convert `List` to `ListBuffer` and they are not compatible.

So what you can do is change `ListBuffer` to `List` as

```
val component = data.get("viewed_objects").get.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, Any]]]
```

but that would be useless type casting as `data.get("viewed_objects").get` is already of `List[Map[String, Any]]` type

so just doing

```
val component = data.get("viewed_objects").get
//component: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]] = ...
```

would be enough

I hope the answer is helpful

**Update**

You have commented as

> btw, if data value is data:Map(), that means an empty Map, your code would return exception None.get exception. How to handle it gracefully?

for that you use `Try` `getOrElse` as

```
val component = Try(data.get("viewed_objects").get).getOrElse(List(Map.empty[String, Any]))
```

Or you can use *pattern matching* as

```
val component = data.get("viewed_objects") match {case Some(data) => data; case None => List(Map.empty[String, Any])}
```

Comment: btw, if data value is data:Map(), that means an empty Map, your code would return exception None.get exception. How to handle it gracefully?

Comment: thank you, I use your codes, its type is scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, I want to traverse it, using for (element <- component), but it doesn't work. how to traverse it or convert to List type?

Comment: the issue was because the try or pattern matching was returning Any . now that I have modifed the answer to return List[Map[String, Any]] from both. the for or foreach should work

Comment: I am trying, for (element <- component) {} still has the error: value foreach is not a member of Any; I has been trying for(element <- component.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, Any]]])